# When I plug in a USB with windows 8 dev to an xp machine and restart it won't install

Tags: windows-xp, partitioning, iso-image, windows-8-preview

I've installed windows 8 on a blank machine and it worked. Now I'm trying t dual boot Windows 8 on my XP computer. I plug in the USB with the ISO and then restart my computer but when I do my computer just boots into XP without giving me the option to install Windows 8 to my partitioned drive. I also tried with a DVD but had the same problem.

Please help!

Thanks!

When I plug in a USB with windows 8 dev to an xp machine and restart it won't install

Comment: Are you expecting that the Windows 8 ISO is a running OS? Its an install package, that you have to go thru and add to your XP machine in a new partition (if you have a free partition or want to have XP overwritten with Win 8). I don't see a problem here.

Comment: No.I know I can't boot from the USB. I want to install it onto a partition and the way to do that us by starting up the computer with the USB in it. However my computer seemingly disregards the USB and just boots to XP.

Comment: That's correct. Unless you add a boot record/file to the USB, and then use either the boot menu and/or modify the bios boot order - its just a non-bootable drive. But you should still be able to continue with the install by manually clicking on the setup.ext file on the USB.

Comment: If I click the setup.ext file will that install windows 8 on the xp partition or will it give me an option to install on the other partition. Sorry for asking so many questions, and thanks.

Comment: Running setup.ese for the Win8 Dev Preview will prompt you where you want to install it. It shows the potential locations. Using the Win8 Preview is not recommended on a machine you intend to continue to use for things your depend on (ie you don't mind losing).

Comment: If you don't already have an empty partition or second empty HD on your XP machine, the install will write over the XP as a clean install. (ie no dual boot).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bootable USB or DVD from the downloaded ISO.  Booting to a device with the ISO file on it will not work to get the Dev Preview installed.

If you need a tool to burn the ISO to DVD, use [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) (it is free and a really good software).

Comment: I know I can't boot from the USB. I want to install it onto a partition and the way to do that us by starting up the computer with the USB in it. However my computer seemingly disregards the USB and just boots to XP.

Comment: @Jack - You still need to make the USB device bootable.  Windows is installed in an OS-like environment.  If your not getting an option to boot from even a media disk, CHANGE YOUR BIOS settings!

Comment: How? Sorry I'm just not sure what to do once I'm in bios settings(f2 at boot up).

Comment: How? Sorry I'm just not sure what to do once I'm in bios settings(f2 at boot up).

Comment: All machines are different, but there should be a boot tab, and under that something labeled "boot order". If USB as a bootable device is supported by that bios, it will be listed there (some older machines with usb aren't usb bootable). If it is there, move it above HD.

Comment: Hi,i did that but it still boots to windows XP bypassing the USB. A while back I installed windows 7 (beta so I deleted later) using a DVD and it worked so now I have a windows 7 (full version, not beta) DVD and wheni put it in the drive and restart the computer the computer still byoasses it and loads to XP. This may sound dumb, but is it possible that a virus is overriding the system and telling it to boot straight to XP rather than to read the drives at startup.

Comment: Can you force a paticular boot option in the BIOS? Most Dells offer via F12 the ability to select the boot device rather than the default order...when booting to an optical disc you still need to hit a keyboard key to verify otherwise the computer will skip it and go back to the defaults.